# PySpark Job Lose Tasks and Exceptions When Reading a CSV created Dataframe

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm not sure how to continue diagnosing this problem, but here's what I have so far.

I create a dataframe with a csv file (I have no choice in this matter, and I would prefer it wasn't csv too...)

I ingest like so:

```
table = sqlContext.read \
    .option('header','true') \
    .option('inferSchema','true') \
    .option('parserLib', 'univocity') \
    .load(path, 'com.databricks.spark.csv')
```

Now, if I perform *any* operation, it blows up. Specifically, if I do the following on my local machine:

```
table.count()
```

Everything works.

If I launch an ec2 cluster and then perform the same operation, I get the following errors:

> WARN  [2016-03-25T05:29:02.061] org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 1519, ip-10-0-35-54.ec2.internal): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String

and then...

> ERROR [2016-03-25T05:29:05.554] org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times; aborting job

`py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 1522, ip-10-0-35-56.ec2.internal): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String`

When I read in other avro files, it all works perfectly. Not sure what's going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Note, the csv file isn't that large. About 800K rows.

Comment: what version of Spark are you running on your local machine and on your ec2 instance?

Comment: @Salmonerd 1.6.1 on ec2 and 1.6.0 on local